# C++ Template Limiting Member Constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

This is my first foray into C++ templates, and I'm trying to construct a `BinaryTree` template to help me with a Project Euler problem; however, I seem to be getting an error where `BinaryTree` class doesn't recognize all the constructors of the `BinaryTreeNode`!  Here's a snippet of the code.

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTreeNode
{
private:
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _left;
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _right;
    T* _value;

public:
    BinaryTreeNode();
    explicit BinaryTreeNode(const T& value) : _value(&(T(value))) {}
    BinaryTreeNode(BinaryTreeNode<T>& left, BinaryTreeNode<T>& right, const T& value) :
        _left(&left), _right(&right), _value(&(T(value))){}
};
```

The BinaryTree class

```
#include "BinaryTreeNode.h"
template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _root;
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _current;
    unsigned int size;

public:
    BinaryTree() : size(0), _root(0), _current(0) { }
    explicit BinaryTree(BinaryTree<T>& leftTree, BinaryTree<T>& rightTree, const T& value) : 
        size(leftTree.Size() + rightTree.Size() + 1), _root(leftTree.Root(), rightTree.Root(), value), _current(_root) {}
    explicit BinaryTree(const T& value) : size(1), _root(value) {}
    const BinaryTreeNode<T>& Root() const { return *_root;}
};
```

I'm getting these errors.

```
error C2359: 'BinaryTree<T>::_root' : member of non-class type requires single initializer expression
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'BinaryTreeNode<T> *'
error C2439: 'BinaryTree<T>::_root' : member could not be initialized
```

The `BinaryTreeNode` constructor of `(BinaryTreeNode<T>&, BinaryTreeNode<T>&, const T& value)` works when I include it in my main code, but it doesn't seem to work under my `BinaryTree` template.  Anyone know why?

Comment: You are missing `;` at the end of your classes. The `explicit` keyword is only useful on constructor with a single parameter. `_value(&(T(value)))` initializes `_value` with a pointer to a temporary that will be destroyed right after the statement, resulting in a dangling pointer. `BinaryTreeNode::BinaryTreeNode()` is declared but not defined, is this on purpose? If so, you should make it private.

Comment: @Luc Touraille Really a good answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @neuront Not really since I did not take the time to find what the real problem was, that was just some issues I spotted quickly.

Comment: What does this tree do, that `std::set` can't do?

Comment: @UncleBens: nothing yet.  I'm just using this as an exercise for learning C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your initialization expression `_root(leftTree.Root(), rightTree.Root(), value)`, `_root` is a *pointer*. You can only initialize it to another pointer. Perhaps you mean to initialize it to a pointer to a new node constructed on those arguments?

This could be done like this: (*updated after your edit*)

```
_root(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(leftTree.Root(), rightTree.Root(), value))
```

However, this is very dangerous (think about an exception in the allocation), and you should probably avoid using raw pointers in your class design and instead use smart managing pointers.

Similarly, the initializer `_root(value)` does the wrong thing, you might want:

```
_root(new BinaryTreeNode<T>(value))
```

(Also note that you should initialize members in their order of declaration.)

Update: I changed the first constructor call following your edit, but as @Luc says, your constructors take non-const arguments but `Root()` only provides a const reference, so you still need to fix that.

Comment: Your immediate solution didn't work, but it looks like I'm going to have to investigate (google) smart pointers.  EDIT: From your immediate solution, I get a `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const BinaryTreeNode<T>' to 'BinaryTreeNode<T> &'

Comment: You're not saying what the `Root()` function does, so I did some guess work. Provide more specifics and we can take a look. A `std::shared_ptr` is probably a good start for your situation.

Comment: Another edit mistake, I should probably proofread my questions before submitting!  Anyways, I added the Root function.

Comment: @Nick: `Root` returns a reference to a **const** `BinaryTreeNode`, while `BinaryTreeNode`'s constructor takes a reference to a **non-const** `BinaryTreeNode`, hence the error. You could provide a non-const overload of `Root` that returns a non-const reference.

Comment: Ok done.  But that still doesn't solve my error: nowhere in my BinaryTree class can I use the constructor: `_root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(BinaryTreeNode<T>& left, BinaryTreeNode<T>& right, T& value)`.  But I can use that exact same constructor outside of the BinaryTree class.

Comment: Thanks for seeing through my const-incorrectness!  That ended up being the solution.  Sorry I didn't recognize this as the answer right away.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed `;` after both class declarations!

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTreeNode
{
private:
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _left;
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _right;
    T* _value;

public:
    BinaryTreeNode();
    explicit BinaryTreeNode(const T& value) : _value(&(T(value))) {}
    BinaryTreeNode(BinaryTreeNode<T>& left, BinaryTreeNode<T>& right, const T& value) :
        _left(&left), _right(&right), _value(&(T(value))){}
};

template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _root;
    BinaryTreeNode<T>* _current;
    unsigned int size;

public:
    BinaryTree() : size(0), _root(0), _current(0) { }
    explicit BinaryTree(BinaryTree<T>& leftTree, BinaryTree<T>& rightTree, const T& value) : 
        size(leftTree.Size() + rightTree.Size() + 1), _root(leftTree.Root(), rightTree.Root(), value), _current(_root) {}
    explicit BinaryTree(const T& value) : size(1), _root(value) {}
};
```

Comment: Absentminded mistake from copying!  Will fix original post.  Good catch though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need a constructor in the form `BinaryTree<T>();`

Comment: Nope, not it, just tried it!  The problem is from the `explicit BinaryTree(BinaryTree<T>&, BinaryTree<T>&, const T&)` constructor.  Thanks for the suggestion.